# Setting mask (halo) for labels in Python script?

Tags: arcpy, labeling

I currently am writing a python script and using a lot of the arcpy mapping module functionality. I have been using the LabelClass of the arcpy mapping module to automate the display of labels with my ptyhon script.

Is there a way to set a mask (halo) for labels with ArcPy?

Comment: there is nothing in the label class that would indicate such functionality.  Based upon the help files
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000002t000000.htm
this is it.

Comment: This would make a good ArcGIS Idea if you have time to write it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible via what is exposed to Python.

However, you can author a layer file and import it with the labels already defined for your workflow.

Comment: Unfortunately no, because my labels are constantly changing throughout the python script.  I was thinking about making two point files and labelling twice.  A bold thick white label and then place on top a black label to create a halo.

Comment: For posterity - hopefully you created a new layer with the same data source, rather than having 2 point files to maintain?